# What prevents an app impersonating another native windows client with Oauth2/PKCE

Tags: oauth2

Given a native windows app, with a redirect URL of example://redirect, what prevents a malicious user from taking the Client ID (public), and creating a new app that sets itself up to be the target of the `example://` protocol?

There are two significant implications that I'm trying to tackle.

The first is the reputation of client owners. If a client is impersonated, and damage is done, all logs would point to their client being the culprit.

The second is long term (remembered) grants. If a user has given permission to this trusted client, it obviously would be bad if an impersonating client can easily gain an access token simply because they used the same client ID.

A natural following question to this, is how can it be prevented? In-browser SPA's have the advantage of registered HTTPS addresses, but custom protocols have no such registration process and can be changed relatively easily.

Comment: 1) This method is not as secure as other OAuth methods. 2) The client is authenticating to their own account and granting you permission to access their account based upon request scopes. This affects their security not yours. 3) It is up to your backend to decide to trust this client to access your resources. 4) Do not trust this type of client credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the response @JohnHanley. My main concern for user security would be if the authority server had a prior persistent grant on record for that user-client combo, so immediately approved the application for access.

Comment: Why would that be a problem? OAuth is designed to support refreshing of tokens. You can issue tokens that do not refresh. Do not request the scope offline access when requesting the first token. At this level you need to be very specific on which OAuth server you are using. Google is different than Okta for example.

Comment: If app A (client ID: 123) were to be running on my PC with a redirect URL of eg://redirect, and it prompted me for access (with "remember" ticked), that would create a persistent grant.

Later, app B (a malicious app) prompted access with client ID 123 as well (copied from app A), the consent prompt would not appear, as the persistent grant exists, it would immediately redirect back to the redirect URL (eg://redirect), which app B may have overriden to open app B. Thus, app B now has access to my resources, without ever actually asking for my consent.

Comment: If you have malicious apps on your computer, you have a bigger problem to worry about. In regards to "remember me", if you are concerned, then do not use that feature (token refresh aka offline access). As I mentioned, do not trust that form of authorization.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, it's been helpful for wrapping my brain around the situation.